# saving the xml file generated through cakephp 2.3 serialize function

Tags: cakephp

I am using cakephp 2.3 and using the default code from the cookbook. The xml is generated automatically, without having to create any view files.

```
class PostsController extends AppController {
public function index() {
$this->set(’posts’, $this->paginate());
$this->set(’_serialize’, array(’posts’));
}
}
```

However, I do not want to display the XML. Instead I want to save the generated XML file in the document root upon click of a button as Posts.xml. How can I do this? Please help.

Comment: did you try something?

Comment: no. I searched thoroughly in the cookbook, and searched the internet. I have no clue as to how to do this. If you can give me some inputs or clues, I can try it immediately.

Comment: I don't understand if you want to save the file to the server, or to force the download client side

Comment: Actually I want to save the generated XML file on the server as posts.xml in the document_root/files folder.

Answer (score 2):

You might not have look thoroughly enough:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#sending-files

It clearly states how to send files with the appropriate headers via response object.

So in your controller action, add:

```
$this->response->download('filename_for_download.xml');
```

Comment: Thanks Mark. I reviewed this section too. Unfortunately I am unable to understand how to get this to work. What should go into the controller, and what should go into the view. Currently, the serialize function does not require to create a view.

I find the cookbook difficult as it only provides very small code pieces, and no solved examples or longer complete code block, apart from the simple blog posts tutorial.

Comment: It also clearly states that using an example. Read it again! I updated my answer, though, for the sake of completeness.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mark. This was really helpful. I can see the generated XML file popup for saving. 
Is it possible to save the generated file automatically to the server webroot/files folder? Please guide me. Thanks a lot for your quick help. I really appreciate it!

Comment: Saving it in webroot or any other file system folder is totally different from what you just described. And yes, you could render it all into a string which you then can store somewhere. But that will not make it downloadable by default via the same controller action. You should think about what you really want to do here.

Comment: Thanks Mark. Saving the XML file in the webroot is what I wanted originally, and I mentioned it in my original question. Currently I can download the file when it pops up to save. But would like to automate the saving, as there are over 50 tables, and the entire schema needs to be saved as XML. So I am looking for automatic save of the xml files to the wwwroot/files folder. Please let me know if you have any suggestions on this. Thanks a lot.